# DHTML Window Widget jquery version

Tags: jquery, dhtml

We currently use the DHTML Window widget from: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow/index.htm

Is there a jquery alternative that offer the same sort of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery Window Plugin](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/) does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty. For example, this standard `Dialog` component from jQuery UI:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/